# JMeter file download is not working in CentOS

Tags: linux, jmeter

I have a JMeter script which downloads a file which is around `500 MB` from the cloud. The script is working fine on the Windows machines and taking approximately 30 minutes to download. But it is not working in the `CentOS`.

JMeter is crashing after 10 minutes and nothing gets downloaded. I'm using Save Response to a file listener to download the file. I tried with increasing the heap memory of JMeter to `2 GB to 8 GB` and still not working. What is the difference between Windows and CentOS here? I monitored the CPU and Memory utilization on the server which also looks fine.

Heap memory configuration in jmeter.sh
JVM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m" jmeter.sh

While executing the script iM getting the error 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap usage
[image: error]

Comment: is it the same version of JMeter and Java on Windows and Linux? did you try to use exactly the same memory parameters on CentOS (by editing either `jmeter` or `jmeter.sh`)? and how JMeter is crashing?

Comment: Please add the jmeter log error stacktrace

Comment: You need to run jmeter on CentOS with sh jmeter.sh command. If you are changing any memory configs, those changes should be made to jmeter.sh file not jmeter.bat

Comment: How to change the memory configs in jmeter.sh file? I couldn't see any memory configs in the jmeter.sh file.

Comment: Both CentOS and Windows has same version of Java and JMeter.

Comment: @RJM it's explained on top of `jmeter.sh` itself: you need to uncomment `JVM_ARGS=` and set it to the same params as windows: `JVM_ARGS="-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m"`

Comment: I made the following changes in JMeter.sh

JVM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m" jmeter.sh

While executing the script iM getting the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap usage

Comment: how do you start JMeter?

Comment: From JMeter bin folder i executed the below commands .

chmod +x *.sh jmeter jmeter-server ,
sh jmeter.sh -n -t test.jmx -l log.jtl

It gave me the error command not found. Then i tried the following which is giving me out of memory error.

./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l log.jtl

Comment: I tried the below commands also 
chmod +x *.sh jmeter jmeter-server, ./jmeter.sh -t test.jmx

Now getting the message 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.